# Nil coalescing operator for dictionary

Tags: swift, swift-dictionary

Trying to access/ check the key in dictionary and add values.

`myDict["Algebra"]` initially returns `nil`.
Why "nil coalescing" doesn't work here?

```
var myDict = [String : [Int]]()
myDict["Algebra"]?.append(contentsOf: [98,78,83,92]) ?? myDict["Algebra"] = [98,78,83,92]
```

Comment: `=` has a lower precedence than `??`, so you should be careful (and put parentheses).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying use like yours give you and error :
**Left side of mutating operator has immutable type '[Int]?'**

By putting parentheses it will be no compile error and it will work

```
var myDict = [String : [Int]]()
myDict["Algebra"]?.append(contentsOf: [98,78,83,92]) ?? (myDict["Algebra"] = [98,78,83,92])
print(myDict) // ["Algebra": [98, 78, 83, 92]]
```

Swift Documentation is here for [Infix Operators](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/swift_standard_library/operator_declarations).

Answer (score 5):

While this works with parentheses, the problem you're trying to solve is exactly what the `default` subscript does, without abusing the `??` operator into an implicit `if` statement with side-effects:

```
myDict["Algebra", default: []].append(contentsOf: [98,78,83,92])
```

You may also find this syntax a little clearer:

```
myDict["Algebra", default: []] += [98,78,83,92]
```